# composite functions and injection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

I want to know if my attempts at parts b,c are correct for the following problem.

a)Prove that the composition of one to one functions is a one to one function.
b)Show by example that the converse is not true.
c)Show that if g $_0$f is one to one then f must be one to one.

These are my answers.
**b)**

Let A={1,2,3} , B={2,4,5,6,13}
Define f:A  ->B , g: B->C. by
f={(1,2),(2,4),(3,6)}
g={(2,3),(4,9),(6,13),(5,13)}
Then g $_0$f={(1,3),(2,9),(3,13)}
Hence  g $_0$f is one to one.
But g(5)=g(6)=13
and 5 $\neq$ 6.
Hence g is not one to one.Thus the converse is not true.

**c)**

Suppose f:A  ->B , g: B->C and g $_0$f is one to one.
For contradiction suppose f is not one to one.
Then there exists x$_1$, x$_2$ $\in$ A such that f(x$_1$)=f(x$_2$) and x$_1$ $\neq$ x$_2$.

Since x$_1$, x$_2$ $\in$ A , there exists c$_1$, c$_2$ $\in$ C
 such that  g(f(x$_1$))=c$_1$ ,g(f(x$_2$))=c$_2$.
 Since g $_0$f is one to one and x$_1$ $\neq$x$_2$, c$_1$ $\neq$ c$_2$.

Thus g(f(x$_1$)) $\neq$ g(f(x$_2$)).
  As f(x$_1$)=f(x$_2$) and g is well defined this is a contradiction.
Hence our assumption is false.
Therefore f is one to one

Comment: Looks okay, except that in (b) you didn’t define the set $C$; it appears that you intended it to be $B$.

Comment: Alternatively for (c) you can argue directly as follows:

Suppose $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$.  Then $g \circ f (x_1) = g(f(x_1)) = g(f(x_2)) = g \circ f (x_2)$ and since $g \circ f$ is one-to-one, we have that $x_1 = x_2$.

Comment: Thanks.I've forgotten to write C.  C={3,9,13}